# Links open firefox with starting page, instead of link content (linux)

Tags: web-browser

### Problem:

For some mysterious reason, when I open a link in firefox, a new firefox instance opens. Also **note** instead of the content of the link, my home-page shows up.

Instead I would like a new tab to open in my running instance and actually show the content of the link.

but I would like to make it work for firefox?

I am running Fedora Linux 21, with emacs 24.4.1.

### Troubleshooting:

1) If I set my browser to chrome/eww, then it works:

```
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-generic
      browse-url-generic-program "google-chrome")
```

2) I tried loading my emacs with `emacs -q` and dissabling all firefox plugins, but the result was the same.

### EDIT: Solution:

As per post below, I rebuild emacs from sources and that solved the problem.

In case anyone reads this, I wrote a blog entry on how to rebuild emacs on fedora: 
https://coffeeorientedprogramming.wordpress.com/2015/03/11/how-to-compilebuild-emacs-from-scratch-on-fedora/

For Ubuntu:
http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/building_emacs_on_linux.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to a Firefox upgrade that changed the command line parameters.
It's fixed in both trunk and `emacs24` git branch.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had to figure out how to rebuild emacs from sources, but once done the issue is fixed. Thank you .

Comment: Do you happen to know what the command-line parameters to give are?